# Azure CLI - issue creating a Azure Data Factory Linked Service with a credential

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-cli, azure-managed-identity

I am using Azure CLI to set up a data factory service. I have a linked service of type 'Azure Sql Server' that I created using the ADF studio UI. I have used a user assigned managed identity to connect to my Sql Server. To do this I had to create a credential in ADF as a reference to the managed identity.

I need to reverse engineer this process to create the linked service with Azure CLI. I am able to create the linked service, but cannot create the credential.

Can someone provide some assistance please.

Answer (score 0):

> Verifying Azure Data Factory Linked Service Configuration in Azure Portal

To use a Managed Identity for authentication, you need to set up an Azure Data Factory (ADF) Linked Service with credentials. You can automate this process with the Azure CLI, which lets you manage Azure resources, including Data Factory resources. However, you should be aware that the Azure CLI may not have direct commands for creating Data Factory credentials. In that case, you will have to use ARM templates or the REST API for some configurations.

My demo **`Linkedservice.json`**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('dataFactoryName'), '/MyLinkedService')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "properties": {
        "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
        "annotations": [],
        "typeProperties": {
          "connectionString": {
            "type": "SecureString",
            "value": "[concat('Server=tcp:', parameters('sqlServerName'), '.database.windows.net,1433;Database=', parameters('databaseName'), ';Authentication=Managed Identity;')]"
          }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    }
  ],
  "parameters": {
    "dataFactoryName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Azure Data Factory"
      }
    },
    "sqlServerName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Azure SQL Server"
      }
    },
    "databaseName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Azure SQL Database"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You deploy this ARM template using the Azure CLI. The command to deploy an ARM template

```
az deployment group create --name MyLinkedServiceDeployment --resource-group demovksb --template-file linkedservice.json --parameters dataFactoryName=demovkdf sqlServerName=demovkserver databaseName=demosqldb
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]